# Issue with 3 SQL Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have problems to solve following sql statments.

1. List all books (BUCH.BUCHTITEL und BUCHART.BUCHARTBESCHREIBUNG) which are from „Naturheilkunde“
2. All books which are written from  „Agatha Christie“ .
3. Estimate the Value of all Books.

relation Schema:
[image]

Comment: What are your "issues" with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not be so hard ...

1) All books with the subject "Naturheilkunde"

```
SELECT 
    b.BUCHTITEL,
    ba.BUCHARTBESCHREIBUNG  
FROM Buch AS b INNER JOIN BUCHART AS ba 
ON b.ART = ba.BUCHART
WHERE 
      ba.BUCHARTBESCHREIBUNG = 'Naturheilkunde';
```

2) All books written by Agatha Christi:

```
SELECT 
    b.BUCHTITEL
FROM Buch AS b INNER JOIN  AUTOR AS a 
ON b.AUTOR = a.AUTORNUMMER
WHERE 
      a.VORNAME = 'Agatha' AND a.NACHNAME = 'Christi';
```

3) Waht do you mean by "estimate"?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PREIS * BESTAND) AS Summe
FROM Buch
```